# Typeahead.js with image and footer

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead

I've just downloaded myself the typeahead.js plugin and would like to know how to display an image next to my search result (similar to the way it appears on the typeahead.js home page) as well as a small footer underneath each search result with done small text.

My idea is that my search results will each have a green, amber or red circle next to each result with some small footer text underneath.

Can anyone point me to any working examples of this. The typeahead.js page does not show an example with an image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ProfileCard u-cf Typeahead-suggestion Typeahead-selectable">
    <img class="ProfileCard-avatar" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000017912577/de7d4a2860762bd2f7d7dbef3c2385ee_normal.gif">

    <div class="ProfileCard-details">
      <div class="ProfileCard-realName">typeahead.js</div>
      <div class="ProfileCard-screenName">@typeahead</div>
      <div class="ProfileCard-description">A flexible JavaScript library that provides a strong foundation for building robust typeaheads. Brought to you by @TwitterOSS.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="ProfileCard-stats">
      <div class="ProfileCard-stat"><span class="ProfileCard-stat-label">Tweets:</span> 48</div>
      <div class="ProfileCard-stat"><span class="ProfileCard-stat-label">Following:</span> 11</div>
      <div class="ProfileCard-stat"><span class="ProfileCard-stat-label">Followers:</span> 1068</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Not sure about what are you exactly trying to achieve but if you are looking at showing images and footers in the search results, there is a good example on the typehead.js website itself.

furthermore, the results are displayed in a div so inside that div, you can design it any way you like.